# Cannot float text block to the right of an image

Tags: html, css

I have a 310px width x 128px height image.  I have a block of text I want to float to the right of it.

Like this, where X is image and Y is text

```
XXXXXXXXX  YYYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXXX  YYYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXXX  YYYYYYYYY
```

I've tried lots of things, but this was the try I thought for sure would work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        hr {
            border: 0;
            width: 80%;
            color: #347fb9;
            background-color: #347fb9;
            height: 5px;
        }
        .addressText {
            font: Lucida Grande;
            color: black;
            font-size: large;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <hr />
    <img src="img/invoiceLogo.png" style="width: 320px;" />

    <p class="addressText">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br />
consectetur adipiscing elit<br />
Donec purus urna, dictum<br />
sed egestas mattis, aliquet
    </p>

    <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

This is just producing the following

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYY
YYYYYYYYYYYY
YYYYYYYYYYYY
```

I feel like it's a stupid question, but I can never seem to get floats right.  Shouldn't floating the text to the right of a 320px image, given that the screen is say 500px wide, make it appear directly to the right of the image?

Comment: Have you tried adding float: left to the image as well as using display:inline-block on both elements, plus removing the float on the text?

Comment: Which browser are you using? On Firefox 23 is the image on the left and the text on the right

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
.addressText {
    display: block;
}
```

It will still push the text to the bottom if the window is too small to fit it on the right side of the image, but if it's big enough it should be close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try floating both elements to the left (I added a class to img):

CSS:

```
.addressText {
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.image {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="img/invoiceLogo.png" style="width: 320px;" class="image"/>
```